# Falcor and PouchDB working together to provide good developer and user experience

Tags: javascript, offline, pouchdb, falcor

In [this interview](https://devchat.tv/js-jabber/185-jsj-pouchdb-with-nolan-lawson) Nolan Lawson talks a little about how [PouchDB](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb) relates to [GraphQL](https://github.com/facebook/graphql) and [Falcor](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor):

> I think you're right that all of these projects are in the same family, in the same vein of saying, “Hey, we spend enough time writing custom REST servers that are different every time, for every single app that we write. And we always get it wrong and we always mess it up.” And it's always hard to do Ajax, right? How do you handle failed requests? How do you handle not re-syncing the entire database every time when all you need to do is just sync a little bit to get up-to-date with where you left off the last time that you stopped syncing? And all of these libraries solve that in different ways.

They are used together in the [falcor-router-demo](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router-demo), but just for ease.

My question is if it makes sense to combine, Falcor's declarative data fetching API and the granularity of [Json Graph](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html), with PouchDB's data replication for offline-first user experience. And since Falcor uses it's own method of caching, how would it work together with a client side PouchDB database.

Comment: From what I've seen, it doesn't make much sense to combine them if all data will be stored in a database compatible with PouchDB. For initial data fetching it would make more sense using something like https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load

Comment: I'm not sure how much sense it makes to combine the two. If you're already using Falcor, I don't think PouchDB would add much value: you already get data replication and offline cache, albeit approached slightly differently. The reverse probably applies too.

Comment: Falcor does data replication as well? Does it work with localstorage?

Comment: It's not that falcor *does* data rep, but that it will pull in all data requested into a local cache until it is overwritten, it exceeds its expiry date, or memory becomes limited (LRU). If you have the "holy grail" of one data call to populate your tree, then the difference is negligible. For me, the key is that the client must ask for precisely the data it wants; it will get nothing else. And yeah - you can certainly [save the cache to local storage](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/Model.html#getCache) and [restore it later](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/Model.html#setCache).